# How to implement Google Map to my Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model has the address attribute and I want to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to sample.address, googlemapaddress %>
```

So that when I click on the link, it will redirect me to the actual google map address.

How do I implement this feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= link_to sample.address, "https://www.google.com/maps/place/#{sample.address}" %>
```